# Calculate all cyclic subgroups of a group under multiplication of modulo n (group theory)

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, mathematics

The task was to calculate all cyclic subgroups of a group \$ \textbf{Z} / n \textbf{Z} \$ under multiplication of modulo \$ \text{n} \$ and returning them as a list of lists. The first level has all subgroups and the secend level holds the elements of these groups.

The programm first calculates the numbers \$ \text{g} \$ that are coprimes of \$ \text{n} \$. Each element of a cyclic subgroup can than be obtained by calculating the powers of \$ \text{g} \$.

A explanation of what cyclic groups are can be found on wikipedia: [Group (mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Modular_arithmetic).

```
# coding=utf-8

"""Basic usage:
$ python subgroups.py 1
[[1]]
$ python subgroups.py 7
[[1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 6]]
"""

import argparse
from fractions import gcd


def main():
    """Prints out the results of `calculate_subgroups()`
    """

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('modulus', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.modulus > 0:
        print(calculate_subgroups(args.modulus))
    else:
        print("Please enter an integer > 0.")


def calculate_subgroups(modulus):
    """For a group of integers modulo n, n is called the `modulus`. With the
    modulus of a cyclic group, calculate all subgroups of Z/nZ.
    See Wikipedia for reference:
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Modular_arithmetic

    Basic usage:
    >>> calculate_subgroups(1)
    [[1]]
    >>> calculate_subgroups(4)
    [[1], [1, 3]]
    >>> calculate_subgroups(7)
    [[1], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 6]]
    >>> calculate_subgroups(9)
    [[1], [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8], [1, 4, 7], [1, 8]]
    >>> calculate_subgroups(18)
    [[1], [1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17], [1, 7, 13], [1, 17]]
    """

    # All cyclic groups have the trivial subgroup [1]
    subgroups = [[1]]
    coprimes = get_coprimes(modulus)

    for i in range(1, len(coprimes)):
        # Subgroups of cyclic groups always contain 1
        potential_subgroup = [1]

        exponent = 1
        coprime_potency = pow(coprimes[i], exponent, modulus)
        while coprime_potency != 1:
            potential_subgroup.extend([coprime_potency])
            exponent += 1
            coprime_potency = pow(coprimes[i], exponent, modulus)

        potential_subgroup = sorted(potential_subgroup)

        if potential_subgroup not in sorted(subgroups):
            subgroups.append(potential_subgroup)

    return subgroups


def get_coprimes(number):
    """Returns the coprimes of a number as a list.
    Basic usage
    >>> get_coprimes(7)
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    >>> get_coprimes(10)
    [1, 3, 7, 9]
    """

    coprimes = []

    for i in range(1, number + 1):
        if gcd(number, i) == 1:
            coprimes.extend([i])

    return coprimes


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run

```
if potential_subgroup not in sorted(subgroups):
```

you turn an `O(n)` lookup into an `O(n log n)` one. Don't do that! Just use

```
if potential_subgroup not in subgroups:
```

Better, make `subgroup` a set of tuples and write:

```
subgroups.add(tuple(potential_subgroup))
```

which will deduplicate for you. Note that this isn't likely to be faster because hashing is `O(length of tuple)` and `length of tuple ≫ length of subgroups` in the common case.

If you take this into account and extract subgroup generation into a separate function, you end up with:

```
def calculate_subgroups(modulus):
    def get_group(coprime):
        return tuple(sorted(generate_subgroup(coprime, modulus)))

    return {get_group(coprime) for coprime in get_coprimes(modulus)}

def generate_subgroup(factor, modulus, start=1):
    while True:
        yield start
        start = (start * factor) % modulus

        if start == 1:
            return

def get_coprimes(number):
    return (i for i in range(1, number) if gcd(number, i) == 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Two things to consider:

- `pow` is an overkill. To calculate the subgroup, I'd continuously multiply a power by the generator:

  ```
  subgroup = [1]
  power = generator
  while power != 1:
      subgroup.append(power)
      power = (generator * power) % modulus
  ```

  BTW, now you don't have to special case a trivial subgroup.
- I would also strike out calculated powers from the list of candidate generators (that is, `coprimes`). This way you'd avoid recalculating the same subgroup over and over again.

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks nice, is nicely formatted (10/10 according to `pylint`, nothing wrong according to `pep8`, etc), is properly documented, properly tested. I'd like to start by congratulating you for this.

I still have a few things to say.

---

In `def get_coprimes(number)`, you are using `extend` to add elements one by one by replacing `coprimes.extend([i])` with `coprimes.append(i)`. However, the pythonic way to write this is to use a list comprehension:

```
return [i for i in range(1, number + 1) if gcd(number, i) == 1]
```

---

In `def calculate_subgroups(modulus)`, the loop is very unpythonic. The very point of the `for` loop as it is defined in Python is to prevent you from having to deal with indices.

```
for c in get_coprimes(modulus):
    if c > 1:
```

is all you need (on top of replacing `coprimes[i]` with `c`). It can hardly becomes easier.

The check `if c > 1` is somewhat artificial. If I was to write the code, I'd write `get_coprimes` in such a way that only numbers bigger than 1 are in the returned list.

---

Here again, you use `extend` instead of `append` :

```
        potential_subgroup.append(coprime_potency)
```

---

You should compute successive powers by performing the multiplications as you do. If you do this, you do not need `exponent` anymore :

```
    coprime_potency = c
    while coprime_potency != 1:
        potential_subgroup.append(coprime_potency)
        coprime_potency = (coprime_potency * c) % modulus
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting my updated code here for reference. Have to look through some topics like list comprehension.

**Changes:**

- Utilizing list comprehension in `get_coprimes()`
- Replacing unpythonic index-based for-loop with Josay's suggestion
- Checking against a unsorted instead of a sorted list

**Code:**

```
import argparse
from fractions import gcd


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('modulus', type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.modulus > 0:
        print(calculate_subgroups(args.modulus))
    else:
        print("Please enter an integer > 0.")


def calculate_subgroups(modulus):
    subgroups = [[1]]

    for coprime in get_coprimes(modulus):
        potential_subgroup = [1]

        coprime_potency = coprime
        while coprime_potency != 1:
            potential_subgroup.append(coprime_potency)
            coprime_potency = (coprime_potency * coprime) % modulus

        potential_subgroup = sorted(potential_subgroup)

        if potential_subgroup not in subgroups:
                subgroups.append(potential_subgroup)

    return subgroups


def get_coprimes(number):
    return [i for i in range(2, number+1) if gcd(number, i) == 1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```